# Chaining a number of transitions with the state Monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, state-monad, scalaz7

I am starting to use the state monad to clean up my code. I have got it working for my problem where I process a transaction called CDR and modify the state accordingly.
It is working perfectly fine for individual transactions, using this function to perform the state update.

```
def addTraffic(cdr: CDR): Network => Network = ...
```

Here is an example:

```
scala> val processed: (CDR) => State[Network, Long] = cdr =>
 |   for {
 |     m <- init
 |     _ <- modify(Network.addTraffic(cdr))
 |     p <- get
 |   } yield p.count
processed: CDR => scalaz.State[Network,Long] = $$Lambda$4372/1833836780@1258d5c0

scala> val r = processed(("122","celda 1", 3))
r: scalaz.State[Network,Long] = scalaz.IndexedStateT$$anon$13@4cc4bdde

scala> r.run(Network.empty)
res56: scalaz.Id.Id[(Network, Long)] = (Network(Map(122 -> (1,0.0)),Map(celda 1 -> (1,0.0)),Map(1 -> Map(1 -> 3)),1,true),1)
```

What i want to do now is to chain a number of transactions on an iterator. I have found something that works quite well but the state transitions take no inputs (state changes through RNG)

```
  import scalaz._
  import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
  type RNG = scala.util.Random

  val f = (rng:RNG) => (rng, rng.nextInt)
  val intGenerator: State[RNG, Int] = State(f)
  val rng42 = new scala.util.Random
  val applicative = Applicative[({type l[Int] = State[RNG,Int]})#l]

  // To generate the first 5 Random integers
  val chain: State[RNG, List[Int]] = applicative.sequence(List.fill(5)(intGenerator))
  val chainResult: (RNG, List[Int]) = chain.run(rng42)
  chainResult._2.foreach(println)
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to adapt this, but I can not get they types signatures to match because my state function requires the cdr (transaction) input

Thanks

Comment: Just to check if I understood your question correctly: you want to know how to apply this pattern to, say, 5 CDRs sequentially? e.g. Given an initial State, you want to apply the first CDR to that state, the second CDR to the resulting State from the previous step and so on....correct?

Comment: Yes, but to CDRs on an iterator, I can apply them manually like in one after the other by hand, but my goal is to be able to run this against a block of any size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TL;DR***
you can use `traverse` from the `Traverse` type-class on a collection (e.g. `List`) of `CDR`s, using a function with this signature: `CDR => State[Network, Long]`. The result will be a `State[Network, List[Long]]`. Alternatively, if you don't care about the `List[Long]` there, you can use `traverse_` instead, which will return `State[Network, Unit]`. Finally, should you want to "aggregate" the results `T` as they come along, and `T` forms a `Monoid`, you can use `foldMap` from `Foldable`, which will return `State[Network, T]`, where `T` is the combined (e.g. folded) result of all `T`s in your chain.

**A code example**
Now some more details, with code examples. I will answer this using [Cats `State`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html) rather than Scalaz, as I never used the latter, but the concept is the same and, if you still have problems, I will dig out the correct syntax.

Assume that we have the following data types and imports to work with:

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.State

case class Position(x : Int = 0, y : Int = 0)

sealed trait Move extends Product
case object Up extends Move
case object Down extends Move
case object Left extends Move
case object Right extends Move
```

As it is clear, the `Position` represents a point in a 2D plane and a `Move` can move such point up, down, left or right.

Now, lets create a method that will allow us to see where we are at a given time:

```
def whereAmI : State[Position, String] = State.inspect{ s => s.toString }
```

and a method to change our position, given a `Move`:

```
def move(m : Move) : State[Position, String] = State{ s => 
  m match {
    case Up => (s.copy(y = s.y + 1), "Up!")
    case Down => (s.copy(y = s.y - 1), "Down!")
    case Left => (s.copy(x = s.x - 1), "Left!")
    case Right => (s.copy(x = s.x + 1), "Right!")
  }
}
```

Notice that this will return a `String`, with the name of the move followed by an exclamation mark. This is just to simulate the type change from `Move` to something else, and show how the results will be aggregated. More on this in a bit.

Now let's try to play with our methods:

```
val positions : State[Position, List[String]] = for{
  pos1 <- whereAmI 
  _ <- move(Up)
  _ <- move(Right)
  _ <- move(Up)
  pos2 <- whereAmI
  _ <- move(Left)
  _ <- move(Left)
  pos3 <- whereAmI
} yield List(pos1,pos2,pos3)
```

And we can feed it an initial `Position` and see the result:

```
positions.runA(Position()).value // List(Position(0,0), Position(1,2), Position(-1,2))
```

*(you can ignore the `.value` there, it's a quirk due to the fact that `State[S,A]` is really just an alias for `StateT[Eval,S,A]`)*

As you can see, this behaves as you would expect, and you can create different "blueprints" (e.g. sequences of state modifications), which will be applied once an initial state is provided.

Now, to actually answer to you question, say we have a `List[Move]` and we want to apply them sequentially to an initial state, and get the result: we use `traverse` from the [`Traverse` type-class](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html).

```
val moves = List(Down, Down, Left, Up)
val result : State[Position, List[String]] = moves.traverse(move)
result.run(Position()).value // (Position(-1,-1),List(Down!, Down!, Left!, Up!))
```

Alternatively, should you not need the `A` at all (the `List` in you case), you can use `traverse_`, instead of `traverse` and the result type will be:

```
val result_ : State[Position, List[String]] = moves.traverse_(move)
result_.run(Position()).value // (Position(-1,-1),Unit)
```

Finally, if your `A` type in `State[S,A]` forms a `Monoid`, then you could also use `foldMap` from `Foldable` to combine (e.g. fold) all `A`s as they are calculated. A trivial example (probably useless, because this will just concatenate all `String`s) would be this:

```
val result : State[Position,String] = moves.foldMap(move)
result.run(Position()).value // (Position(-1,-1),Down!Down!Left!Up!)
```

Whether this final approach is useful or not to you, really depends on what `A` you have and if it makes sense to combine it.

And this should be all you need in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it got me on the right track. I had to do some small adjustmentsI; first defined an alias because State has too many "holes":

       type NetworkState[A] = State[Network,A] 

then I created my list of CDRs to feed

       val miscdrs: List[CDR] = (new CDRFromRandom(5).buffer map { x => x.getCDR}).toList
       val result: NetworkState[List[Long]] = cdrs.traverse[NetworkState, Long](processCDR _)

I had to give some help to the compiler too...

       val result = cdrs.traverse[NetworkState, Long](processCDR _)
       result.run(Network.empty)

Comment: I now have two more questions though:
First, is it possible to do this with an iterator to keep it lazy?
Second, I am not really interested in the List as it can grow really big (several hundred millions elements, can I get rid of it and keep just the last value?

Thanks

Comment: To answer the first question: you don't need `Iterator` to keep it lazy. As mentioned, `State[S,A]` is an alias of `StateT[Eval,S,A]`, and what `Eval` does is exactly that: it makes it lazy.

Comment: if you don't need the whole `List` as a result, you can use `foldMap` from `Foldable` instead of `traverse`. The concept is similar, but given a `List[Move]` and a function `Move => State[Position, String]`, it will return `State[Position, String]`, where the final `String` is the result of the `combine` operation for the `Monoid` of `String` in this case (which is concatenation, but you can change it to what you need in your case).

Comment: finally, if this response was useful, please make it the answer.

Comment: Another thing you could do, if you don't care at all about the `A` type, is to use `traverse_` instead of `traverse`. That will return `State[S,Unit]`, meaning that you only really care about the state, after all changes have been applied.

Comment: I could not make the traverse_ one get to work. In the meantime I use a State[Network, Unit] that hopefully should not eat all my memory.